# Java: Will if-statments not work if I have two or more conditionals in the statement?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, operators, equals

There is probably an obvious answer. This question might have already been asked but I don't know how to word the question. I'm working in Java and in this moment, I am reading the input text from the command line and converting that stuff over to strings.

I am, for sure, inputting the x character into the command line and whether I set the code to

```
!(first.equals("x")) or (first.equals("x"))
```

I still get the system.out output text. I noticed that if I remove the || and the following equals snippet it works as intended and continues onto the code. However, I have to have either x or y be options for the first arg string. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
private something(String[] args) 
{       
    first = args[0];
    second = args[1];
    third = args[2];

    if (!(first.equals("x")) || !(first.equals("y")))
    {           
        System.out.println("First is the problem " + first);
    }
}
```

Here is the ouput:

```
First is the problem x
```

Edit: I also did this and got the same result:

```
if (first.equals("x") == false || first.equals("y") == false)
    {
        System.out.println("First is the problem " + first);
    }
```

I'm using this if-statement as a check for whether or not the two values are inputted. If they aren't then the if-statement should trigger.

It works when I have it like this, but I end up losing the y:

```
if (first.equals("x") == false)
    {
        System.out.println("First is the problem " + first);
    }
```

Comment: Your `if` statement prints `x` because the value of your variable `first` is always `x`. What should be your expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to work. The `if` statement returns as true if `args[0]` equals either `x` or `y`. `!(first.equals("x"))` means that it is true for every string except `"x"`, so this would do the opposite of what you want. Also, you need to define `first`, `second`, and `third` otherwise it won't compile.

Edit:
Looking at your edit, it appears the issue is caused by `||`. Since this means 'or', `first` only has to not equal either `x` or `y` for the if statement to run. Therefore, since it can't equal both at once, the if statement will always run. You should use `&&`(and) instead. Also, notice that `== false` can be replaced with `!`.

For example:

```
if (!(first.equals("x")) && !(first.equals("y")))
{
    System.out.println("First is the problem " + first);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**first** is either NOT "x" or NOT "y". This will always be true for whatever string **first** is set.

=> Are you not republican or are you not democrat? ;)